# copy and rename file with create date (Batch script)

Tags: batch-file

I have some of log files formatted like this `"name.log"`

I would like to copy those from one folder to another folder like

`xcopy  /y  "C:\Folder1" "D:\Folder2"`

Adding I need to rename file with created date of original file (no copy file) so that the text file in Folder2 would be like `"yyyymmddhhmm.log"` if some file has the same name (date of creation) it will be overwritten.

I have a code with help of @Wes Larson but there is something wrong.

```
set Source=C:\Users\user1\Desktop\1
set Dest=C:\Users\user1\Desktop\2
if not exist %Dest% md %Dest%
for /F %%a in ('dir /b "%Source%\*.txt"') do call :Sub %%a
goto :eof

:Sub
set "filename=%1"
for /F %%s in ("%Source%\%1") do  if %%~zs==0 goto :eof
set "datepart="
FOR /F "tokens=1-5 delims=/-: " %%a IN ('dir /tc "%filename%" ^| findstr "%filename%"') DO (
    IF "%%c" neq "" SET "datepart=%%c%%a%%b%%d%%e"
)
FOR /F %%a IN ("%filename%") DO (
    set "NewName=%%~na %datepart%%%~xa"
)
xcopy /y "%Source%\%filename%" "%Dest%\%NewName%*"
GOTO :EOF
```

The problem is that If I don't put the .bat in the same folder that origin files (Folder1),some files aren't change name. For example, if it is out some files change name with old name and one white space. The command windows tell me that it doesn't find the file when it get the creation date. It's very strange because some files are copied well.

What do I need to solve this problem?

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose issues when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Comment: Hello, I understand you but the problem is that I don't have results so I'm sure that my code is wrong. When I execute the bat a command windows open and later close and I can't see anything.

Comment: The easy way to debug is temporarily remove `@echo off`, then go into `cmd.exe` and call your batch file. `cmd.exe` should remain open on most errors, and can let you see if a syntax error, or a bad exit placement is happening.

Answer (score 0):

**Before we get to an answer:  When troubleshooting/debugging batch scripts, don't use `@echo off`.**  It's great once you have it working the way you want, but comment it out when you need to see what your code is doing line by line.  Also, you'll want to open a cmd window and run your script from a command line, so the window doesn't close as soon as your script finishes.

Now on to your code.  This `for` loop is part of your problem:

> ```
> FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=/-:" %%a IN ('dir /tc "%filename%"') DO IF "%%c" neq "" SET "datepart=%%a-%%b-%%c"
> ```

Firstly, you haven't set `%filename%`, so this loop will fail.  You should probably have a line in your `:Sub` like this:

```
set "filename=%1"
```

Now, assuming that `%filename%` is fixed, by the time this loop has finished, your `%%a`, `%%b`, and `%%c` variables have been set to the values in the last line of output from the command `'dir /tc "%filename%"'`, which is something like `X Dir(s)  XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX bytes free`, and isn't the information you're looking for.

So, instead, you can tweak it a little so that you pipe the output of `dir` to `findstr`, looking for just the one, single line that you want to use, like this:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=/-:" %%a IN ('dir /tc "%filename%" ^| findstr "%filename%"') DO (
    IF "%%c" neq "" SET "datepart=%%a-%%b-%%c"
)
```

But then, you have another problem: your `%datepart%` looks like `MM-DD-YYYY  hh`.  This is because you changed your `delims` from the default (which includes spaces and tabs), to only the specified characters.  Also, from your question, you want to also include hour and minute all formatted as "yyyymmddhhmm.log" , which means you'll need those next two tokens, too.  Then your line becomes this:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/-: " %%a IN ('dir /tc "%filename%" ^| findstr "%filename%"') DO (
    IF "%%c" neq "" SET "datepart=%%c%%a%%b%%d%%e"
)
```

Next, your nested `for` loop is confusing, unnecessary, and causing problems:

> ```
> FOR /f %%a IN ("%filename%") DO FOR /f %%d IN ("%datepart%") DO (
>     set NewName="%%~na %%d%%~xa
>     xcopy e/d/y "%Source%\%OrgName%" "%Dest%\%NewName%"
> )
> ```

You already have the `%datepart%` variable, and you don't need to turn it into one of the `for` `%%d` variables to be able to reference it.  So it becomes much simpler when you do it like this:

```
FOR /f %%a IN ("%filename%") DO (set "NewName=%%~na %datepart%%%~xa")
```

Also, because you run into delayed expansion issues, it's simpler to take the `xcopy` command out of the loop.

And once again, you have a variable `%OrgName%` that you never set.  Fortunately, this is actually unnecessary as you already have the original file name captured as `%filename%`.  So your overly complicated nested `for` loop becomes this:

```
FOR /f %%a IN ("%filename%") DO (
    set "NewName=%%~na %datepart%%%~xa"
)
echo xcopy e/d/y "%Source%\%filename%" "%Dest%\%NewName%"
```

Comment: I have a problem with some files that don't write the date on folder 2.I run the script from command windows and I can see the message "It doesn't find the file". I've written the full question below. Thank you very much.